# Custom CSS For Similar Items With Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, calendar

I am populating a calendar with events from database. Each event has a certain color code that needs to be used when it shows up on the calendar. How can I achieve this in AngularJS?

To be specific, I am using the following calendar: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar

This is what my HTML with the calendar looks like. As you can see, I have just set some static colors.

```
<style type="text/css">

  .my-custom-class a {
    color: #FF3D7F !important;
  }

  .event-custom {
    background-color: #10a3ff;
   }

</style>

<div ng-controller="Calendar as vm">
<a href="/#/add-activity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a>
<a href="/#/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></a>
  <ng-include src="'partials/calendarControls.html'"></ng-include>
  <mwl-calendar
    events="vm.events"
    view="vm.calendarView"
    view-date="vm.viewDate"
    cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen">
  </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

And this is my Calendar controller responsible for populating things.

```
//Controller providing the calendar functionality
app.controller('Calendar', ['$scope','$rootScope','$resource','moment', function($scope, $rootScope, $resource ,moment) {
    //Acquire events from API, in case Calendar was the starting point of the application 
    var Activities = $resource('/api/activities');
        Activities.query(function(activities){
            $rootScope.activities = activities;
            //console.log($rootScope.activities);   
        });

    //console.log($rootScope.activities);

     var vm = this;
     var events = [];

    //define the calendar on rootScope, so it has access to the Events data from the other controllers
    $rootScope.calendar = new moment();

    angular.forEach($rootScope.activities, function(eachActivity){
        //console.log(eachActivity.events);
        if (eachActivity.events.length > 0){
            angular.forEach(eachActivity.events, function(eachEvent){
            //console.log(eachEvent);      
            var entry = {
                    title: eachActivity.title,
                    type: "custom",
                    startsAt: eachEvent.startDate,
                    endsAt: eachEvent.endDate,
                    incrementBadgeTotal: true,
                    cssClass: 'my-custom-class'
                }
            console.log(entry); 
            events.push(entry); 
            }); 
        } 
    });

    vm.events = events;
    console.log(vm.events);

    vm.calendarView = 'month';

    vm.viewDate = moment().startOf('month').toDate();
    vm.isCellOpen = true;

}]);
```

When I set the "type" attribute of an event to "custom," it makes it utilize the `.event-custom` class from above. How can I populate these events with different colors? Color of each event will be contained in `eachActivity.color`

Comment: If you need to share certain similar css features to many different elements I suggest you to give a look at `less`.

Comment: Will it allow parameters to be passed to CSS or style things dynamically as AngularJS populates them?

Comment: It will allow you to pass variables to css attributes. For example, if you know that you'll need a certain width for all the buttons, you can create a less variable containing the width needed and calling it on the buttons. It's very useful if you have these kind of needs.

Comment: Got it. I have started looking into it. Do you have any advice on LESS vs SASS? Also, what if you wanted to have a different width of buttons, depending on, say, the value they contain? Does LESS have a  way of doing that?

Comment: I'll answer you in some hours, when I'll be home

Comment: For example, lets suppose you need to use always **#f4f4f4;** color in many css classes. You can set up a **.less** file for colors, e.g. **colors.less**, that contains variables like **@colorGreyLight:#f4f4f4;**. Once you have defined a certain set of less variables, you can just assign this value to your css classes like **color: @colorGreyLight;**. First, you need to import the less file like **@import "colors.less";** at the beginning of the css file. Now, for your purpose, I would attach a **ng-style="color: {{myColour}};"** to every button and directly changing it from js.

Comment: Would LESS be compiled into CSS upon every request made by the user? In my case, users will be seeing different buttons and colors.